# Java3D Applet source files

Tags: java, applet, java-3d

I have a Java3D application, where the applet is embeded in a html file with syntax "`<applet code="iiit.vlabdemos.science.science$MyApplet"  width="990" height="700" title="EPR">`". I am actually looking for the source files[ie .class/.jar/.jnlp files] of that applet in the application repository. But I am unable to trace it out. Is it that the applet is running form some server? Can someone explain what the applet syntax means.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "code" contains the name of the applet class but when it doesn't point to a .class file, usually you find a reference to a JNLP file (attribute "jnlp_href") or to a JAR (attribute "archive"). No the applet isn't running from a server, it is downloaded and executed within the web browser. Enable the logs and the trace in the Java console to see which JAR or class file is loaded.

Comment: Sir, thank you for repsponding. I have looked for .jnlp/.jar/.class files with the application repository/source files but I haven't found any. What could be the alternative for finding the executables of this applet?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I got the solution for this.

Comment: Glad to know you've just solved your problem. Sorry for the off topic but keep in mind that you must respect the license of the code source and the binaries you're going to get. If there is no license, it's under copyright by default according to the Bern convention.